# How are the modules xml.etree.ElementTree and xml related?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am not a professional programmer, and I'm just starting to study python.
I just figured out that just because I could do:

```
>>> from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element
>>> var = Element("Something")
```

doesn't mean I can do:

```
>>> import xml
>>> var = xml.etree.ElementTree.Element("Something")
```

In fact, doing this:

```
>>> import xml
>>> dir(xml)
['_MINIMUM_XMLPLUS_VERSION', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
```

etree doesn't even appear as one of the methods provided by xml.
What is the relation between xml and xml.etree.ElementTree?
Why can I not see etree as one of xml's methods?

Comment: You can only use modules once they are imported. Sometimes you have to do the importing yourself and sometimes one module you import automatically imports its own submodules. `xml` has multiple submodules and you likely won't use all of them. So, you have to import the ones you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xml.etree` is a child module to `xml` [package](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages). It only shows up in `xml`'s namespace after you `import xml.etree`. A parent may import its child modules on its initialization (e.g. in 2.7, `os` imports `os.path`<sup>1</sup>) but it's not required to do so.

Conversely, when you import a module from a package directly, the package is automatically imported first.

Strangely, I couldn't find any phrasing in the docs stating this. But a test shows that this is exactly what happens:

---

```
$ cat test/__init__.py

print "package init"
import traceback
traceback.print_stack()

$ cat test/module.py

print "module init"
import traceback
traceback.print_stack()

$ python
<...>
>>> import test.module
package init
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    traceback.print_stack()
module init
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test\module.py", line 3, in <module>
    traceback.print_stack()
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>this is not documented though so don't rely on this</sub>