# Import names from many submodules of a package efficiently

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

I have the following files structure

```
| main.py
| Apis
|--| __init__.py
   | submodule1
   |--| __init__.py
   |--| Main.py
   | submodule2
   |--| __init__.py
   |--| Main.py
```

In each one of the Main.py files, I have a function main() which is the sub-module main function.
How can I import those functions correctly?

What I currently do is

```
from APIs.submodule1.Main import main as submodule1
from APIs.submodule2.Main import main as submodule2
```

But I already have a big list of sub-modules and it doesn't look right...

Comment: Btw [Python's naming convention suggests](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) using lowercase_with_underscore for module names. I can at least confirm those are way easier to type.

Comment: try `from APIs import submodule1, submodule2...` and then use them like `submodule1.main()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguably, the most manageable way is to not use `from ... import` at all:

```
import APIs.submodule1
import APIs.submodule2

<...>
APIs.submodule1.main(<...>)
```

I prefer this way whenever I can because it allows me to instantly see what comes from where when navigating through this code later.

---

If there are many submodules to import, the logic in package's `__init__.py` ([that runs when first importing the package or any submodule thereof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35819416/how-are-the-modules-xml-etree-elementtree-and-xml-related/35820024#35820024)) can import them so as not to repeat that code in every program:

`APIs\__init__.py`:

```
import .submodule1   #or import just `main's instead if you don't need anything else
import .submodule2
<...>
```

Whatever you place into the package's namespace here will be seen in it if you import just the package:

`your_program.py`:

```
import APIs
<...>
APIs.submodule1.main(<...>)
```

With this logic, you can still cut on typing `APIs` by doing `from APIs import *`, getting `submodule1`, `submodule2` etc into your namespace which may be sufficient to "instantly see what comes from where" if the submodule names are unique enough.

---

Finally, you *can* reduce code repetition:

```
import importlib
for module in ('submodule1','submodule2',<...>):
    vars()[module] = importlib.import_module(module,'APIs')
del module, importlib
```

But this will make it harder to search for references across the codebase. So doing all the imports in the package looks preferrable 'cuz it's only needed to be done once.